# Someone explain to me a few step of this Java Big O code

Tags: java, big-o

```
for( int bound = 1; bound <= n; bound *= 2 ) { 
     for( int i = 0; i < bound; i++ ) { 
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j += 2 ) { 
        ... // constant number of operations 
        } 
        for( int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2 ) { 
        ... // constant number of operations 
     } 
   } 
}
```

The correct answer is O(n^2).

I know the third for loop has complexity O(n+2) , The fourth for loop has complexity O(log n), since two loops are not nested, they are added together right? So what should I do with the first two loops, I know it's log(n) and n. so my question what should be the next step, how do I know which loop to add or multiply. Basically I'm just confused how they get to O(n^2).

Comment: O(n+2) is not a time complexity, I think you mean O(n) - linear

Comment: No, I think it's O(n^2).  There are only two nested loops here.  The two inside aren't nested, so it's not O(n^3).  They simply add.

Comment: for the third loop? it does a linear number of operations, from j=0 to n, incrementing by 2

Comment: Think of it like this - If you have O(n^2) + O(n) and n is like 100000000000 does the O(n) really matter at all anymore? Since it doesn't you just remove it and are left with only O(n^2).

Comment: @duffymo: The loops `bound` (O[log n]), `i` (O[bound]), and `j` (O[n]) are nested three levels deep, though, no?

Comment: Looks to me like the first inner loop ends before the second one begins, so they add.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. one last thing, the last two loops are not nested together, so you add them right? and since all four loops are nested in one loop, you multiply them for the final step?

Answer (score 6):

The value of `bound` in the first loop doubles each iteration up to `n`: `1, 2, 4 ... n`

The second loop runs up to the value of `bound`, totaling: `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n = O(n)`

The third and fourth loops are `O(n)` and `O(logn)`, which added together is just `O(n)` because `n` dominates `logn`.

So the first two loops together are `O(n)` and the inner two loops are `O(n)`. Multiplied together, they're `O(n^2)`.

Comment: **plus one** To see why the two outer loops add up to O(n): 1+2+4+8+..+N = 2N-1. Just like how binary numbers work. So that is indeed O(N)

Comment: can I ask why is the outer loop not log n, it keeps multiply by 2. shouldn't it be N * log N?

Comment: @JohnHenderson The outer loop is indeed `O(log(n))`, but adding the second loops gives `O(n)`. Because the iterations of the second loop depend on the first loop through the `bound` variable, we need to consider them both together.

Comment: Thank you! so you are saying that the second loop is N because it dominates log n, am I correct?

Comment: @JohnHenderson It's more like both loops contribute to the time complexity. Counting the number of iterations for both loops gives the sum 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n which is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The rules for O is O(a + b) = O(max(a, b)), O(const * a) = O(a). (max is in complexity not as in actual numbers)

So the innermost loops are both O(n), together they are O(n + n) = O(max(n, n)) = O(n).

The middle loop is O(n) but the outer one is O(log n) this comes out as O(n * n * log n). This is not an error O is only an **upper** limit for the operations, anything O(n) is O(n*n) too.

But we can do better!

Each time the middle loop executes, it double the number of operations it does. it starts out as 1 next is 2, 4, 8 etc. together both the middle and the outermost loop execute 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + n operations. this is O(n + m - 1), where m is the first power of two after n - 1. but because of that n <= m < 2 * n so m = O(n), O(n + m) = O(n + n) = O(n)

so the outmost and the middle loop together are O(n) and the innermost is also O(n), and that means that the whole thing is O(n * n) or O(n ^ 2) as you wrote

Comment: fourth one is not linear its logarithmic, it multiplies index by 2 on every run

Comment: Oh, I see my bad. Thanks. Not going to correct it, though, its the same anyway.

Comment: so can I ask if the outer loop is log n, and the middle and inner loops are N, so log n * n * n is N^2 because it dominates log n?